Как отменить git pull
git pull удалил код с локального проекта
Я пописала немного кода для проекта, не сделала коммит и выполнила git pull. Мой код естественно исчез. Можно его как-то вернуть?
Смогла восстановить файлы в WebStorm. View -> Recent Changes -> Выбрать сохранение до git pull.

естественно исчез - увы, не естественно. похоже, вы привели не всю относящуюся к делу информацию.

Я сделала коммит проекта, т.к. доделала целый блок. Начала делать следующий блок, сделала часть, а для другой часть используются компоненты, которые делал мой коллега. Я попросила его залить эти компоненты на github. К слову, я ждала 3 дня пока он зальет. И сегодня с утра, не подумав, сделала git pull. И исчезло то, что я не закоммитела.

Возможно, при пуле изменений, возник конфликт( вы правили тот же файл, что был изменен в гит) и вы вместо коммита локальных изменений сделали restore  и все вернулось в исходное состояние. Одно можно сказать точно, что если пропало то, что не было закоммичено, то это не вернуть

Очень печально(

git по умолчанию никогда не удаляет незакоммиченные изменения. Так что если они пропали, то значит вы самостоятельно явно согласились на это. Читайте внимательно сообщения и убедитесь что понимаете последствия.

Вам бы не дали сделать git pull, при наличии не откомиченного кода. Вам бы предложили сделать git add . git stash
Если вы сделали git stash попробуйте сделать git stash pop

Без проблем сделался git pull (прикрепила к вопросу картинку вывода), никаких подтверждений не запрашивал. git stash не использовала.

@МихалеваПолина ну теперь-то конечно пройдёт, никаких изменений же нет.

Это старый скрин

@МихалеваПолина на будущее пайпланй: git add ., git stash, git pull origin branch-name, git stash pop

@antokhio - git add . тут лишний (я про ваш "пайпланй")
